# How to post images on Facebook wall on a single button click from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, facebook

I am making an iPhone app where in the user wants that the selected image should be posted on Facebook wall on a single button click. I have Actionsheet button for this.

I want that both authentication of user (**loginButtonTapped** in tutorial below) and posting images to the wall (**rateTapped** in tutorial below) be carried out on a single button click.

I am using the example on the link below as my reference for posting images on Facebook wall

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

I am a beginner. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the facebook Graph Api for posting images to wall..

Here is the tutorial for this...

http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2

Comment: I want it on single click. Please read the question.Anyways Thanks for your input

Comment: I tried putting both events on the same button click event but then posting invalidates because authentication takes time What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Before sharing you will always have to get the Facebook credentials first by either opening the Facebook App (which is called SSO / Single Sign On) or, in case the Facebook App is not installed, by opening the WebView or Safari. Posting stuff to Facebook can be pretty tricky therefore I wrote a simple lib, called [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare). It is also supporting "single click sharing". You can do things like uploading photos to Facebook easily:

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```

or also create a normal post:

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Simple sharing via Facebook, Email and Twitter for iOS!" 
                        descriptionText:@"Posting to Facebook, Twitter and Email made dead simple on iOS. Simply include BMSocialShare as a framework and you are ready to go." 
                        andHref:@"https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare"];    

[post setImageUrl:@"http://www.blockhausmedien.at/images/logo-new.gif" 
         withHref:@"http://www.blockhaus-media.com"];

[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add on my personal experience on using BMSocialShare created by vinzenzweber here, and my reputation only allows me to answer. It saved me a lot of time and from the trouble of reading Facebook's documentation, for something as simple as sharing an image for my photo app.

Just a couple of pointers on the documentation of it which might not be immediately obvious for someone using the library for the first time.

1. When inserting the snippet into your Info.plist containing the Facebook app id, you need to affix 'fb' in front of the number app id.
2. Besides adding the BMSocialShare.framework into the Xcode Project, you need to manually drag the BMSocialShare.bundle and the FBDialog.bundle in the resources folder of the BMSocialShare.framework, into the Copy Bundle Resources section under Build Phrases of your application's target